# Copiar propiedades de archivos de una carpeta del explorador de archivos a un excel Windows

Tags: excel, windows, csv

Hola estimados tengo una carpeta en el explorador de archivos de Windows con varios videos y quiero copiar y pegar las propiedades `Nombre`, `Fecha`, `Tipo` `Tamaño` y `Duración` a un archivo Excel o csv de todos los videos que hay en la carpeta. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

He tratado de copiar las propiedades pero solo me aparece la opción `Copiar ruta de acceso` que me copia la ruta absoluta del archivo.

Es cierto que se puede hacer de uno en uno pero quiero no quiero hacerlo de forma manual ya son muchos videos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde PowerShell puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma.

```
$Directory = "C:\Carpeta"
$oShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object {
    $Folder = $oShell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
    $File = $Folder.ParseName($_.Name)
    $Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Nombre = $_.Name
        Fecha = ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString()
        Tipo= $_.Extension
        Tamano = "$([int]($_.length / 1mb)) MB"
        Duracion = $Duration
    }
}   | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Nombre, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Salida.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Sale pero sale desordenado 1, 10, 100, 101... 109, 11, 110... 119, 12, 120... 129, 13, 130... 139..., 2, 20, 200... 209, 21, 210... 219... sabes como ordenarlo? Si te fijas en la figura sale ordenado 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13...

Comment: Actualicé el código para ordenar en base a los primeros dígitos del nombre.

Comment: Le doy enter y no me deja completar el comando me sale ">>" cada vez que le doy enter. No me deja completar el comando, ayúdame por favor.

Comment: Ejecútalo desde un archivo o inicia una nueva instancia. El código funciona correctamente.

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error No se puede convertir el valor "Activity+&+Fragment+Lifecycle+Subtitles.zip" al tipo "System.Int32". Error: "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. + }   | sort-object { [int]((($_.Nombre).Split("-")[0]).Trim())} | Expo .. sort-object : No se puede convertir el valor "Developing+Android+Apps+with+Kotlin+Videos.zip" al tipo "System.Int32".
Error: "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto." Lo que pasa es que tengo dos zip en la carpeta.

Comment: te falto un } para hacer que funcione en sort-object

Comment: El código está diseñado para funcionar con nombres de archivo que mantengan este formato cadenanumerica - laotrapartedelnombre.

Comment: Ya ok pero te falto un } en  sort object sin eso no funciona el codigo que se podría hacer para que funcione con el zip y también con ese formato.

Comment: A ese int se le puede poner un if si es letra nomas?

Comment: Modificado para que funcione con cualquier nombre

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado!

Comment: ¿Sabes donde puedo aprender powershell para aplicarlo a otros archivos?